# Capybara #set not filling in the entire string

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

I've got an issue where Capybara will start filling in a string into a text box, however it won't complete the entire string.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it only fills in a partial.  The weird thing is, it is only happening in one place.  It also fails with different character counts.  First time 10 characters will be put in, second time 15 will, etc.

```
input.class
=> Capybara::Node::Element < Capybara::Node::Base

input.path
=> "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div/zip-input-md[2]/div/md-input-container/input"

value
=> "freddie168@example.com"
```

My command is `input.set(value)`.

From capybara-screenshot:
REMOVED

Clearly that first input should be an email address, but it never completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Chrome with selenium-webdriver you're probably running into - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1771&q=sendkeys&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary -  A possible workaround, until Chromedriver fixes the issue, is to sleep for a second or two after calling fill_in on the fields where it's having issues.

Comment: That's exactly it.  Instead I had a second line
`input.set(value); input.set(value) unless input.value == value`